# Disable select, copy and paste of the content of HTML pages in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable select, copy and paste of the content of HTML pages in Mozilla Firefox. I have used jQuery and JavaScript to disable right-click and copy, select, paste of the contents of HTML pages and it's working fine in IE and Chrome, but not working properly in Mozilla Firefox.

Can we disable copy, paste option in Mozilla Firefox?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you do this...

Comment: Please don't do this, it is (a) really annoying to users, and (b) pointless since a determined user will view the source of the page and copy from there. Having said that, if you must do it it is not enough to disable the right-click context menu copy, you also need to prevent Ctrl-C and (somehow) disable the main menu's Edit/Copy option.

Comment: right-click -> view source.  Your script === defeated

Comment: ya i know a good user can disable javascript and do all the things in Mozilla firefox browser but simply i want protect my static courses content from the students that they won't do copy and paste in Mozilla firefox.

Comment: i got the managable solution to prevent ctrl key selection on webpages with Mozilla firefox browser.

Comment: This makes no sense. Aren't we supposed to build new features instead of trying to block basic functionnality (copy/paste) present for more than 30 years... Believe me, your students WILL find a way to get your courses content, whatever you do, just like to probably achieve to get music, movies and books for free.

Comment: Such a pointless thing to do.  Who wouldn't know any one of a dozen ways to get around this?  Especially young students.

Comment: Firebug / Disable javascript and all your work is wasted.  There is no real reason to do this, as it's very easily defeated.

Comment: I build a dragable popup coponent, I would really like to disable the "mark text"-functionality while I drag the popup and enable it, after I dropped it..

I think it is a totally legit requirement. Not need to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and Paste the below javascript in your webpage:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
      function disableselect(e) {             
          return false 
      } 
      function reEnable() { 
          return true 
      } 

      document.onselectstart = new Function("return false") 

      if (window.sidebar) { 
          document.onmousedown = disableselect                    // for mozilla           
          document.onclick = reEnable 
      } 

      function clickIE() { 
          if (document.all) { 
              (message); 
              return false; 
          } 
      } 


      document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false") 

      var element = document.getElementById('tbl'); 

      element.onmousedown = function () { return false; }        // For Mozilla Browser

   </script>
```

Note:If the above code not works for Firefox then add style="-moz-user-select:none" in the body tag which needs to be restricted alongwith the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  first work for block select and second allow to select in textarea and input field.

```
html,body{
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
    }
    input, textarea{
        -webkit-user-select:  text !important;
        -moz-user-select:  text !important;
        -ms-user-select: text !important;
        user-select: text !important;
        -khtml-user-select: text !important;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

A) Apply this code in your html document inside the body tag

`ondragstart=’return false’ onselectstart=’return false’` – to disable copy and paste

B) Use this script in your html document before closing the closing the head tag

```
<script language=JavaScript>
    var message=”Function Disabled! OR whatever text you want to show on right click”;         
    function clickIE4(){
        if (event.button==2){ alert(message); return false; }
    }
    function clickNS4(e){
        if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){ 
            if (e.which==2||e.which==3){ 
                alert(message);
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }
    if (document.layers){ 
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
        document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
    } else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
        document.onmousedown=clickIE4; 
    } 
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function(“alert(message); return false”) 
</script>
```

C) Give security to the contents by using the css elements in body tag

EX:  in css file

```
body {
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
}
```

This is BASIC protection! Advanced users will bypass it with ease by disabling JavaScript on their browser or using firebug.

Comment: Regarding your item "B":  That's 15-year-old code you've posted; written for IE 4 and Netscape 4, both released in 1997.  `if (document.layers)` - no browser could possibly fail that test these days.  Now I've seen everything.

Comment: Also, even if you are using old code, make sure you use the proper apostrophes. " vs ”