# Disabled highlighting and copy content from HTML page, except the content in textfield?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to prevent copy function in html page.
And I see [this topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352367) already.

Now, I am Done and complete  it.

This is code I have used

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.ondragstart = function() { return false; };

</script>
<style type='text/css'>
body
{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Webkit */
    -moz-user-select: none;    /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;     /* IE 10  */
    /* Currently not supported in Opera but will be soon */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>
```

This code can disabled  copy content from **all element** and working well in IE,Chrome and FF

But, my client still want to copy content from any input filed (type=text,textarea)

So
1 ) How to make **text field ,textarea only** be able to copy content ?  And other element still disabled copy content function

Thank you.

And Sorry, for my bad skill in english.

Comment: Very annoying and stupid idea. Don't do this.

Comment: Because My data is confidential for my client. And their staff (only someone) copy data from my program and Bring it to another competotor.

Comment: Anyone with at least a bit of skill will copy anyway :) Everyone has been in this place I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advise your client that once content is served up on the browser, there is no way to protect it. Once it's on the client, it's completely vulnerable. All the suggested prevention measures are silly and futile. Even if you wrap it in a .swf and obfuscate the ActionScript, anybody who wants it can get it.

The answer is to stop and guide your client not bend at their ignorant will.

No offense.

Comment: Yes. If you can see it - you can have it.

Comment: Right, tell your client it's not possible and if he wants to protect the content from copy he needs to keep it off the Internet :)

Comment: I change my point to implement useful logging system. To view who possible to copy data from my system.
Find him to punish.